# How to set release name when using fastlane upload_to_play_store?

Tags: android, fastlane

In play console when you create a release it is possible to provide a release name. But when using **upload_to_play_store** command in fastlane i cannot see a parameter to provide a custom release name when pushing the apk, but takes the version name as the release name. How is it possible to achieve it?

```
   lane :beta do
gradle(
    task: 'assemble',
    build_type: 'Release'
  )
  upload_to_play_store(track:'beta')
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fastlane uses Google's `AndroidPublisherService` to upload APKs. Uploads are done via [its `upload_apk` instance method](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/AndroidpublisherV2/AndroidPublisherService#upload_apk-instance_method). This method does not appear to take an argument for the release name, so fastlane does not expose one.

If you can figure out how to set the release name using `AndroidPublisherService`, you can pass a parameter through to the service via fastlane [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/88255e1cd4ad9724f4ce08ea4e64d6cfa51bf9bb/supply/lib/supply/client.rb#L264-L268).

Answer (score 7):

While [Aaron Brager's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173849/2037924) was correct at the time this was asked, the `version_name` parameter has been added to the `upload_to_play_store` (aka `supply`) action since version `2.136.0` of fastlane.

Following the naming convention of releases in the Google Play Console, you could use something like this in your Fastfile for your lane:

```ruby
version_name: build_number + "(" + version_name + ")", # 1 (0.0.1)
```

So your lane could be fined like this:

```ruby
lane :beta do
  gradle(
    task: 'assemble',
    build_type: 'Release'
  )
  upload_to_play_store(
    track: "beta",
    version_name: build_number + "(" + version_name + ")", # 1 (0.0.1)
  )
end
```

**More info**

- There was an issue raised on this topic on fastlane's GitHub repo that discussed the details of this and confirmed its implementation: [How to set release name when using upload_to_play_store?](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15096)
- This is the original blog post on the Android Developers Blog: [Automating your app releases with Google Play](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/automating-your-app-releases-with.html)
- [fastlane release 2.136.0](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.136.0) (I have not found a reference specifically to this change, but I might have missed it. The version has been referred to in [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15096#issuecomment-559129668), in the issue I mentioned above)